Understanding bracket use in Haskell - Parser that depends on previous parser gives error when using brackets
Ok so I'm trying to learn Haskell.
This is my Parser.
import Data.Char
data Parser a = MkParser (String -> Maybe (String, a))

This is a parser which parses a string once, and depending on what it parses, it runs another parser.
-- second parse depends on the first
(<<<=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
-- a parse, gives Nothing | Just (string, ans depending on a)
(MkParser pa) <<<= k = MkParser sf
    where
        sf inp = case pa inp of
            Nothing -> Nothing
            Just (cs, c) -> unParser (k c) cs

unParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (String, a)
-- applies a parser manually
unParser (MkParser pa) inp = pa inp

Now I use it here (isDigit just checks if the character is a digit, and isAlpha checks if it's a letter). I also use this basic parser (parses if character is what I am looking for)
char :: Char -> Parser Char
char wanted = MkParser sf
  where
    sf (c:cs) | c == wanted = Just (cs, c)
    sf _ = Nothing

Now when I do this:
t = satisfy isAlpha <<<= \x -> satisfy isDigit <<<= \y -> char x

it works!
But the moment I put brackets around this
t = satisfy isAlpha <<<= (\x -> satisfy isDigit) <<<= \y -> char x

it gives an error saying variable x is not in scope... Why?
I initially just placed the brackets because it is easier to read. But turns out my code only works when I remove the brackets.
I tried working with it and realized this works too:
t = satisfy isAlpha <<<= (\x -> satisfy isDigit <<<= \y -> char x)

Question 1) But why? If it does (\x -> satisfy isDigit <<<= \y -> char x) first, it wouldn't know what x is, so how does it work?
Question 2) What's the evaluation order if I don't use brackets?
Question 3) And why does it not work when I do (\x -> satisfy isDigit)?
All questions are related, and I'm sure I am just misunderstanding the evaluation order. I used to program in OOP languages and I feel like I'm misunderstanding the brackets and evaluation order in Haskell?

In your first example:
t = satisfy isAlpha <<<= (\x -> satisfy isDigit) <<<= \y -> char x

It looks like you’re thinking of both the left and right sides of the (<<<=) operator as parsing actions.
But in reality, the left side is a parsing action, while the right side is a function that takes the result of the previous parser, and returns another parsing action.
t = parser1 <<<= parser2 <<<= parser3
  where
    parser1 = satisfy isAlpha
    parser2 x = satisfy isDigit
    parser3 y = char x  -- x isn’t in scope

In your second example:
t = satisfy isAlpha <<<= (\x -> satisfy isDigit <<<= \y -> char x)

That fixes the scoping issue, because it clarifies that the third parser needs to be in the scope of x, in other words, it needs to have x in its closure.
t = parser1 <<<= function1
  where
    parser1 = satisfy isAlpha
    function1 x = parser2 <<<= function3
      where
        parser2 = satisfy isDigit
        function3 y = char x

When you write the lambda without the parentheses, its body is the remainder of the expression, extending as far to the right as possible. So these two forms are exactly equivalent:
satisfy isAlpha <<<= (\x -> satisfy isDigit <<<= \y -> char x)
satisfy isAlpha <<<=  \x -> satisfy isDigit <<<= \y -> char x

Parentheses don’t affect evaluation order, only the grouping of expressions. However, there would be no problem with evaluating the lambda \x -> … first—it just evaluates to a function, which will be applied to an argument later on.
The actual evaluation order in Haskell is determined by pattern-matching, due to laziness. In eagerly evaluated languages, you “push” inputs into functions, and they get called immediately, so the evaluation stack is associated with call expressions f(x). With lazy evaluation, functions are only called when you “pull” outputs from them by pattern-matching, so stack frames come from case expressions instead.
